# How to rewrite URLs using namespaces in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces

I am running Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to set up my routes in order to rewrite URLs using namespaces.

In the routes.rb file I have:

```
namespace "users" do
  resources :account_auth
end
```

So, URLs to "show an"/"create a new" account_auth page are:

```
http://<site_name>/users/account_auths/1
http://<site_name>/users/account_auths/new
```

I would like to rewrite/redirect those URLs as/to

```
# from 'account_auth' to 'auth'
http://<site_name>/users/auth/1
http://<site_name>/users/auth/new
```

**How to do that? If it can be, what kinds of problems could I have?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the :path option:

```
namespace :users do
  resources :account_auth, :path => "auth"
end
```